# Error compiling Fortran code with eclipse... it is OK when using Gfortran via Linux terminal

Tags: linux, eclipse, makefile, fortran

I am trying to compile a .f Fortran code with Eclipse. I have tried both of the below methods from the Eclipse help site:

1. Starting a Project with an Auto-Generated Makefile
2. Starting a Project with a Hand-Written Makefile

However, Eclipse gives multiple different errors... Here are some of the errors:

```
   DIMENSION DDDJ(0:IG,-1:JG)                                          
     1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
../Main1.f:16.5:

    DIMENSION DDDJ(0:IG,-1:JG)                                          
     1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
../Main1.f:19.5:

    DIMENSION MSN(1:NPP)  ! S(x,t)                                      
     1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
Fatal Error: Error count reached limit of 25.
make: *** [Main1.o] Error 1

14:51:55 Build Finished (took 1s.244ms)
```

I have compiled the code in the terminal using Gfortran simply and i have obtained the executable file an obtained the results. But Eclipse did not work for me at all.

I want to debug my code. it is 1236 raws. Can someone help me with Eclipse or any other suggestion?

Comment: To me, this looks like you're trying to compile a free-format file as fixed format (which is the default for `*.f` files). You could try to either rename the file to `*.f90` or add the command line option `-ffree-form`.

Comment: Yes. I think so. I solved the issue by importing the original file into the project not by copying the code into a new source file. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with the form of Fortran file. I was copying the code into a new Fortran source file. I decided to import the file that I have into the project.